# calling store from another store mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx, mobx-react

I have 2 stores like below

**store 1**

```
 export default class ContactInformationModel {
    @observable id;
    @observable type;
    @observable description;
    @observable mode;

    constructor(id,type,description,mode,show) {
      this.id=id;
      this.type=type;
      this.description=description;
      this.mode=mode;

        }
}


export default class ContactInformationController {
    @observable contact_informations = [];

    addContactInformation(data){
      var id= data.hasOwnProperty("id") ? data.id: this.getInsertedId(data.mode); //auto increment for store mvc;
      var type=data.type;
      var description=data.description;
      var mode=data.mode;
      this.contact_informations.push(new ContactInformationModel(id,type,description,mode));
     }



     @computed get SellerContact(){
      return this.contact_informations.filter(c => c.mode == 'seller'); 
     }


}
```

**Store 2**

```
import ContactInformationController from  './ContactInformationController';
var contact_information_store=new ContactInformationController();
export default class SellerController {
    @observable seller = {}; //only one entry

    saveSellerContact(){
      //pull contact_information_store
      var contact_information=contact_information_store.SellerContact;

    }

}
```

when I print contact_information it is blank array however it is rendered in jsx . I am still new on react / mobx , any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have two different instances of the `ContactInformationController` class. It will be resolved if you export an instance of `ContactInformationController` instead, so you use the same instance over the entire app.

```
class ContactInformationModel {
  @observable id;
  @observable type;
  @observable description;
  @observable mode;

  constructor(id, type, description, mode, show) {
    this.id=id;
    this.type=type;
    this.description=description;
    this.mode=mode;
  }
}

class ContactInformationController {
  @observable contact_informations = [];

  addContactInformation(data){
    var id= data.hasOwnProperty("id") ? data.id: this.getInsertedId(data.mode); //auto increment for store mvc;
    var type=data.type;
    var description=data.description;
    var mode=data.mode;
    this.contact_informations.push(new ContactInformationModel(id,type,description,mode));
  }

  @computed get SellerContact(){
    return this.contact_informations.filter(c => c.mode == 'seller'); 
  }
}

export { ContactInformationModel };
export default new ContactInformationController();
```